# Why wont my arrays print?

Tags: java

I have two classes `Hangman` and `words` which are as follows:

Hangman class:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package hangman;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Adam2_000
 */
public class Hangman {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String player = "";
        String selection;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        words words = new words();
        String easyWords1[] = words.easyWords;
        String mediumWords1[] = words.mediumWords;
        String hardWords1[] = words.hardWords;


        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman version 1");
        System.out.println("Please choose a difficulty");
        System.out.println("A: Easy");
        System.out.println("B: Medium");
        System.out.println("C: Hard");


        char iChoice;

        do {
            selection = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        } while (selection.isEmpty());
        iChoice = selection.charAt(0);
        if (iChoice != 'X') {
            switch (iChoice) {

                case 'A':
                    System.out.println("You have choosen easy:");
                    System.out.println(words.getEasyWords());
                    break;

                case 'B':
                    System.out.println("You have choosen Medium");
                     System.out.println(words.getMediumWords());
                    break;

                case 'C':
                    System.out.println("You have choosen Hard");
                     System.out.println(words.getHardWords());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

words class:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package hangman;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Random;


/**
 *
 * @author Adam2_000
 */
public class words extends Hangman {

      String[] easyWords = {"Bee", "Car", "Fish", "Shed"};
      String[] mediumWords = {"House", "Sheep", "Castle", "Phone"};
      String[] hardWords = {"Octagon", "Crocodile", "Chocolate", "Motorbike"};

    public String[] getEasyWords() {
        return easyWords;
    }

    public void setEasyWords(String[] easyWords) {
        this.easyWords = easyWords;
    }

    public String[] getMediumWords() {
        return mediumWords;
    }

    public void setMediumWords(String[] mediumWords) {
        this.mediumWords = mediumWords;
    }

    public String[] getHardWords() {
        return hardWords;
    }

    public void setHardWords(String[] hardWords) {
        this.hardWords = hardWords;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "words{" + "easyWords=" + easyWords + ", mediumWords=" + mediumWords + ", hardWords=" + hardWords + '}';
    }
}
```

When I try to display each array I am getting the references and not the strings can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 4):

> ... I am getting the references and not the strings ...

That's just how the method is defined in the class `Object`.

Since, you can't override that behavior for arrays, you can either iterate through it or you can use [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) (`static`) utility method from [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing something like

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@17bd6a1
```

which is the `Object#toString` respresentation of a `String` array, To display the contents, you can use:

```
Arrays.toString(words.getEasyWords())
```